# Polynomials and their (real) roots

Tags: polynomials, roots, euclidean-algorithm

The following exercise can be found in the book [**Some exercises in pure mathematics**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521095611) *with expository comments* by authors *J. D. Weston* and *H. J. Godwin* (it is the exercise $166$ at page $43$).

> Three polynomials $P$, $Q$ and $R$, of degrees $2n-1$, $2n$ and $2n+1$ respectively, are such that
>
> - $R(x)=3xQ(x)-P(x)$ for all real $x$
> - $P(1)=Q(1)=1$;
> - $P(x)$ contains only odd powers of $x$ and $Q(x)$ contains only even powers of $x$;
> - The equation $Q(x)=0$ has $2n$ real roots in the interval $]-1,1[$, and between each two consecutive roots lies a root of the equation $P(x)=0$.
>
> Prove that the equation $R(x)=0$ has $2n+1$ real roots in the interval $]-1,1[$, and that between each two consecutive roots lies a root of the equation $Q(x)=0$.

What I know so far is that $R(x)$ has only **odd** powers of $x$ and that if you divide $R(x)$ by $3x$ you get $Q(x)$ as quotient and $P(x)$ as remaider. From here on, I have no idea on how to proceed (and don't even know if the usage of Euclid's algorithm is useful).

**Edit**: The exercise does not say, but I think that all roots must be distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set of points A = {${-1, q_1, q_2, ... , q_{2n-1}, q_{2n}, 1}$} where $q_i$'s are the roots of Q(x).

Evaluate R(x) for each consecutive points in A. Then you will find each consecutive pairs give opposite signed results, which mean there exist a point in each consecutive pair satisfying R(p) = 0.

$R(q_i) = 3*q_i*Q(q_i) - P(q_i) = -P(q_i)$

$R(q_{i+1}) = 3*q_{i+1}*Q(q_{i+1}) - P(q_{i+1}) = - P(q_{i+1})$

Since there exists a unique root of P(x) in between each {$q_i, q_{i+1}$} , $R(q_i)$ and $R(q_{i+1})$ have opposite signs.

You should also do the same for the point pairs {$-1, q_1$} and {$q_{2n}, 1$}.

$R(-1) = -3*Q(-1) - P(-1) = -3+1 = -2$ (Q is even, P is odd)

$R(q_1) = 3*q_1*Q(q_1) - P(q_1) = -P(q_1)$

Since P has 2n-1 roots (which is odd) in ($q_1$,$q_n$) then P(1) and P(-1) have opposite signs. Thus P($q_1$) is negative, which means $R(q_1)>0$.

$R(q_{2n}) = 3*q_{2n}*Q(q_{2n}) - P(q_{2n}) =  - P(q_{2n})<0 $, as there is no root of P in [$q_{2n}$,1] and they have the same sign.

$R(1) = 3*Q(1) - P(1) = 3-1 = 2$

Comment: Actually, $P(x)$ has $2n-1$ roots. Another thing is that, if $q^{\star}_i$ is the root of $P(x)$ between $q_i$ and $q_{i+1}$ then, $P(q_i)$ and $P(q_{i+1})$ need not have opposite signs, since the graph of $P(x)$ could be tangent to the $x-$axis at $q^{\star}_i$.

Comment: @Larara Yes, my bad, there are 2n-1 roots of P(x). I will fix the part {$-1, q_1$}. However the second thing you said is wrong because if P(x) is tangent to the x-axis, then it should have a multiple root there, which contradicts the fact that in each interval $(q_i, q_{i+1})$ there exists a root of P(x).

Comment: You're right, I'll edit the question and add the hypothesis that the roots are all distinct. Just one more thing: why $Q(-1)=1$ and $P(-1)=-1$?

Comment: @Larara Actually you don't need to add it, its a conclusion of $Q(x)=0$ has $2n$ roots in $[-1,1]$, which is already stated in the question.

Comment: @Larara Since Q(x) is even polynomial, Q(1)= Q(-1). And P(x) is odd polynomial, so P(1) = - P(-1).

Comment: Yeah, of course, $Q$ has only even powers and $R$ only odd powers of $x$. Sorry for these stupid questions...